# Open multiple different iframes

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have in my site a lot of images and through each one, you can open a different `iframe` that includes an interactive ad that is related to the image from where you opened it.
The thing is that with the code that I´m using, I can only open the first `iframe`.
Here is a demo of my site and what I´m trying to do. You can see that if you click on the images, you will only me able to open the first `iframe`:
http://kickads.mobi/richmediagallery/index_test_iframe.html

I want to know if someone could help me to solve this.

The JS code that I´m using is this one:

```
<script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('MyModal');

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var img = document.getElementById("myImg");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];   

    // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
    div.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    } 

    // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
    img.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }  

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    var freezeVp = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }; 
</script>
```

And here is a demo of how the image opens the iframe:

```
 <div id="ad1" class="portfolio-item deporte col-md-3">
     <div class="portfolio-box">
         <div class="portfolio-image-wrap">
             <img id="myImg" src="img/portfolio/image.jpg" alt="" />
         </div>
         <div class="portfolio-caption-mask" id="myDiv">
             <div class="portfolio-caption-text">
                 <div class="portfolio-caption-tb-cell">
                     <h5 class="alt-title">Puzzle ad</h5>
                     <p>Nike Made to fly</p>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div id="MyModal" class="modal">
     <span class="close">&times;</span>
     <div class="contenido">
         <iframe style="height: 480px; width: 320px" src="http://kickads.mobi/test/ad" frameborder="0"></iframe>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Took a look at your live site. First off you have 3 elements with the same id, you can't do that. You need unique id's. Based on the above js you are failing because you are only getting the first element with that id and nothing else. So you never have a click listener for those.

Comment: I tried by copying the js and use other id´s , but it didn´t work! What I did was, first put another id to each image and iframe, and then copy the js and replace the id. That didn´t work either

Answer (score -1):

As it's been said you cannot call multiple elements using same IDs.
Two elements cannot have the same ID.

If you want to assign multiple elements in the same variable I recomend you to use : `var div = document.getElementsByClassName("name");`
More details [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp).

Comment: Okay! I tried using the class name instead of the ID, but it didn´t work. Nothing happens. What if I change the ID of each img and each div? Can I copy the JS for each element?

Comment: Maybe I misspoke. You cannot just change `document.getElementsById` with `document.getElementsByClassName` I recommend you to read documentation I gave you earlier in my answer to understand the diffrence.
`document.getElementsByClassName("name");`  will call all elements with the `class="name"`. This is what i meant when I said "assign multiple elements in the same variable"
Yes, you can call your element by IDs if they have all unique ID but i recommend to edit your script and create a loop to target each Ad.

Comment: Okay, I will try that! Because each image opens a differente iframe, that´s why I thought that by assigning each element a different ID, it would work. I will now read what you post, and then I will try to change my script. Thank you!

Comment: Well, I find that I have no idea of how to write the script to do what you told me! Is there an easier way?

Comment: Hi again, we answered your question about the problem of the code you provided us (IDs problem). If you have another question you should open an other thread ;).
If you want to provide us your code, use the fiddle option and include all the code you use instead of linking your website (easier for us to help =) ).